# Sendemail function : number of rows to process

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sendemail function which work perfectly with my google sheet.

However, I have to write in the code the number of rows to process. Is there a way to process only filled rows ?

Here is my code :

```js
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL SENT';


function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 4; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 20);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[7] + "," + row[9] + "," + row[13]; 
    var message = row[18]; 
    var emailSent = row[19]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Un nouvel adhérent vous a été affecté';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 20).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can find the last row with content using [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow):

```
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
```

Since you are starting from the second row you should subtract `1` from `numRows` :

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, 20);
```

If there are blank rows you need to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them out:

```
var data = data.filter(function (row) {
    return row[0] != ""; 
});
```

### Solution:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL SENT';
  
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1,numRows-1,20);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var data = data.filter(function (row) {
    return row[0] != ""; 
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[7] + "," + row[9] + "," + row[13]; 
    var message = row[18]; 
    var emailSent = row[19]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Un nouvel adhérent vous a été affecté';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 20).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works (almost) perfectly. I get an error because for the emailAddress. I have formulas in all my blank rows. It seems that the rows are not empty for the script. Any ideas to avoid this error ?

Comment: Can you please try `var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();` instead of `var data = dataRange.getValues();` ? @lfilleur

Comment: Just tried right now, same issue. I've seen that even if the row is empty, a "ghost" value is here

Comment: could you please post a different question regarding this issue. It might be a general issue then. You can then share a sample of your sheet and the script you are using so they other readers can help you (including me). @lfilleur